# On Voice State Update event not working as it should

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I'm working on my bot so that it creates a new channel when someone joins a music vc and that channel has perms for the specific music bot.

**Example:** 1.If the member leaves the channel that was  created would be deleted.

2.If someone is already in the vc then new member joining would just get perms to type in the channel that was created.

3.Lastly if users leave the vc, the channel would get deleted only if no one else is there, if someone is in vc then the channel would still exist.

I also added a check that if the one in the vc is only bot then channel would be deleted.

The code raises no error but it isn't working as it's supposed to work either. Attaching the code for reference and I'm working with Cogs.

**Expected output:** If a user joins vc, a channel with name '・『wave-cmds』' would be created. When the member leaves the channel should be deleted.

**Actual output:** The channel is created but it isn't being deleted.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
from discord.utils import get
import datetime

class Voice(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self,client):
    self.client = client

  @commands.Cog.listener()
  async def on_voice_state_update(self,member : discord.Member, before, after):
    guild = member.guild
    category = self.client.get_channel(858189026661892096)
    wave = self.client.get_user(807585170890555413)

    try:
      if after.channel.id == 858198726803193906:
        if len(after.channel.members) == 1:
        
          channel1 = await guild.create_text_channel(name = '・『wave-cmds』', category = category)
          overwrites = channel1.overwrites_for(member.guild.default_role)
          overwrites.read_messages, overwrites.send_messages = False, False
          await channel1.set_permissions(member.guild.default_role, overwrite=overwrites)
          overwrites = channel1.overwrites_for(wave)
          overwrites.send_messages, overwrites.read_messages = False, True
          await channel1.set_permissions(wave, overwrite=overwrites)
          overwrites = channel1.overwrites_for(member)
          overwrites.send_messages, overwrites.read_messages = True, True
          await channel1.set_permissions(member, overwrite=overwrites)
          await channel1.send (f'{member.mention}')
        
        elif len(after.channel.members) > 1:
          overwrites = channel1.overwrites_for(member)
          overwrites.send_messages, overwrites.read_messages = True, True
          await channel1.set_permissions(member, overwrite=overwrites)
          await channel1.send (f'{member.mention}')

        elif len(before.channel.members) < 1:
          if not member.bot:
            pass
          else:
            await channel1.delete()

    except:
      return




  
def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(Voice(client))
```

Comment: "The code raises no error but it isn't working as it's supposed to work either. Attaching the code for reference and I'm working with Cogs.", is not a question.  Please provide a minimal reproducible problem set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and all relevant code necessary to reproduce the example. What you have provided falls short of this goal. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set. See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.

Comment: @itprorh66 alright sorry, understood I'll take care from next time and I've edited the question too, is it alright now?